# binding different local IP's to one SOAP service client application - is it possibile?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have remote service to ask...

I have a service client defined in service reverence https://xyz/service.php?wsdl

I created it like this:

```
allegro1.servicePort service1;
service1 = new allegro1.servicePortClient("servicePort");
```

I have multiple IP addresses on my local machine to use...

I can change the address used by service client like this:

```
var localIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("111.111.111.111");
var hasLocalAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Any(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork && ip.Equals(localIpAddress));

ServicePoint servicePoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(serviceurl));

servicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = (sp, rm, retryCount) => { return new IPEndPoint(hasLocalAddress ? localIpAddress : IPAddress.Any, 0); };
```

But I don't know how to create multiple instances of my service client.

I tray:

```
allegro1.servicePort service2 = new allegro1.servicePortClient("servicePort");
```

But when i change my local ip address of service1 i chage it to service2 too ...

Is there any method to ask remote soap service from different IP addresses in one application ?

I need to do it because my boss wants to ask the same service from my two **local** IP addresses simultaneously, only method that works is creating many applications - one app one ip - i don't understand why ???

Comment: you are mixing up instances of a host an ip address the service to be archieved. Please clear it up

Comment: i know that my knowledge abaut this is very litlle - i don't understand what do you want from me - but i must write that application so if you can - help me please ...

Comment: please read stackoverflow rules. This is not a platform to outsource your problem.

Comment: i don't want you to write my application for me - i wont you  to answer me a question Is it possiblie to create two instanses of servicePortClient and sending requests from different IP adreses that i have on my local machine to remote service - if answer is yes - give me any link or sugestion how to do it

Comment: @barpas first delete your service url any one can use your service.

Comment: it is public service - i tray to write client that use many local IP addreses ..